# Error getting k8s server version when deploying app with ArgoCD

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, argocd

I am trying to have one central ArgoCD instance that will be able to deploy different applications into different private GKE clusters that are in different project on GCP but under the same organization.

I ran the following commands in order to create service accounts and to enroll destination cluster into a fleet:

```bash
# project which runs the central ArgoCD cluster
HOST_PROJECT="argocd-project"

# project which runs the managed external cluster
FLEET_PROJECT="deploy-project"

# unique name of a cluster in the fleet
MEMBERSHIP_NAME="unique-membership-name"

# enable connectgateway api
gcloud services enable connectgateway.googleapis.com --project=$FLEET_PROJECT

# create argocd fleet admin service account
gcloud iam service-accounts create argocd-fleet-admin --project $HOST_PROJECT

# add iam policy bindings for two workloads
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser --member "serviceAccount:${HOST_PROJECT}.svc.id.goog[argocd/argocd-server]" argocd-fleet-admin@$HOST_PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser --member "serviceAccount:${HOST_PROJECT}.svc.id.goog[argocd/argocd-application-controller]" argocd-fleet-admin@$HOST_PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $HOST_PROJECT --member "serviceAccount:argocd-fleet-admin@${HOST_PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role roles/gkehub.gatewayEditor
```

After that, I also added following annotations to ArgoCD helm chart values:

```yaml
configs:
  cm:
    url: "https://myurl-test.example.com"
controller:
  serviceAccount:
    annotations:
      "iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account": "argocd-fleet-admin@argocd-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
server:
  serviceAccount:
    annotations:
      "iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account": "argocd-fleet-admin@argocd-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  extraArgs:
    - --insecure
```

I also created a k8s secret and deploy it into the same namespace:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: private-gke-cluster
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    argocd.argoproj.io/secret-type: cluster
type: Opaque
stringData:
  name: private-gke-cluster
  server: https://connectgateway.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY_PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/global/gkeMemberships/unique-membership-name
  config: |
    {
      "execProviderConfig": {
        "command": "argocd-k8s-auth",
        "args": ["gcp"],
        "apiVersion": "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
      },
      "tlsClientConfig": {
        "insecure": false,
        "caData": ""
      }
    }
```

However, when I log into the ArgoCD UI and wanting to add a project to this destination cluster I always get the following error

```
Unable to create application: error while validating and normalizing app: error validating the repo: error getting k8s server version: unknown
```

I also executed into the pod and ran the command that is written in secret, to get the credentials:

```bash
argocd-k8s-auth gcp
```

And I can confirm that I can get token with this command. If I change the values.yaml for ArgoCD helm chart and specify cluster (with connectgateway url) and token that I got from the pod, I am able to create a deployment.

I can also get credentials for this cluster (with connectgateway url) with my personal account if I run the following command:

```bash
gcloud container fleet memberships get-credentials $MEMBERSHIP_NAME --project $FLEET_PROJECT
```

I can also impersonate the above service account with the following command and get access to cluster:

```bash
cloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account argocd-fleet-admin@${HOST_PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
gcloud container fleet memberships get-credentials $MEMBERSHIP_NAME --project $FLEET_PROJECT
```

It seems like something is missing in my ArgoCD installation but not really sure what.

---

**UPDATE #1**

If I use token, that I get when executing into the `argocd-server` pod and run command `argocd-k8s-auth gcp`, in the helm values file in the config like these:

```
configs:
  clusterCredentials:
    - name: test-cluster
      server: "https://connectgateway.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY_PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/global/gkeMemberships/unique-membership-name"
      config:
        bearerToken: "ya29.c...."
        tlsClientConfig:
          insecure: true
```

Then I get the same error. But if I specify IP address instead of connectgateway URL, then I can create an app. Are there any limitation on fleet, from where somebody can do a request. I specified authorized IP for control plane to 0.0.0.0/0 for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check first the [IAM policy for a service account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/get-iam-policy), and [its role](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/roles/describe):

```bash
gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy argocd-fleet-admin@${HOST_PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com --project=${HOST_PROJECT} --format=json
gcloud iam roles describe roles/gkehub.gatewayEditor --project=${HOST_PROJECT} --format=json
```

If the existing roles do not have sufficient permissions, consider adding more roles to the service account.
[Common roles](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam#roles) for interacting with GKE clusters include `roles/container.admin` or `roles/container.clusterAdmin`. However, these roles have broad permissions, so you may want to create a custom role with only the necessary permissions if you are following the principle of least privilege.

Review the ArgoCD Helm chart values, especially the `extraArgs: - --insecure` flag. This flag can have implications on how ArgoCD communicates with the Kubernetes API server. See [`argoproj/argo-helm` issue 1123](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm/issues/1123) for illustration.

Also, [`argoproj/argo-cd` issue 13277](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/13277) has a similar error message, pointing to a network error, so debug the network communication (using `curl` or `telnet`) between the ArgoCD instance and the GKE cluster to make sure there are no connectivity issues.

---

> For the debugging purposes I also added owner role to the service acc and removed `--insecure` flag.
> I also ran following command `curl https://connectgateway.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/global/gkeMemberships/$MEMBERSHIP_NAME` and got error saying MISSING auth credentials.
> Which I believe is fine. However, above error in ArgoCD is still present. Any other idea?

You need to check the `argocd-k8s-auth` command within ArgoCD is correctly fetching and using the tokens for authentication.

```bash
kubectl logs -n argocd <argocd-server-pod-name>
kubectl logs -n argocd <argocd-application-controller-pod-name>
kubectl get pods -n argocd
kubectl exec -it -n argocd <pod-name> -- /bin/sh
# try execute the argocd-k8s-auth from there
```

Also, verify if the Kubernetes secret configuration (`private-gke-cluster`) and the `argocd` helm chart values are accurately set up.

```bash
kubectl get secret private-gke-cluster -n argocd -o yaml
# check the server, name and config fields

helm get values <argo-release-name> -n <namespace>
```

---

> But if I specify IP address instead of connectgateway URL, then I can create an app

The Connect Gateway URL may not be resolving correctly within your ArgoCD setup.
Specifying the IP address directly bypasses any potential resolution issues, which is why you are able to create an app in that scenario.

You might want to check DNS resolution and networking configurations within your ArgoCD and GKE setup, and make sure the [Connect Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/multicluster-management/gateway/using) and GKE clusters are correctly configured to handle incoming requests from ArgoCD.

> Even if a do a `curl` to connect gateway address, from the ArgoCD pod, I will get error saying that I am not authenticated / authorized, since I am calling this endpoint without token with `curl`. So this resolution looks OK. However, error still persist.

Given the information, it seems the authentication token is crucial for successful communication with the Connect Gateway. Even though DNS resolution seems fine, the authentication or authorization is not passing through as expected when using the Connect Gateway URL in your ArgoCD configuration.

Comment: Hi @VonC and thank you for answering. Response is too long so this is the pastie link: http://pastie.org/p/0pRcO7nk0wIMj4pZ7T9Kj8 (response from the first command above)

For the debugging purposes I also added owner role to the service acc and removed --insecure flag. I also ran following command `curl https://connectgateway.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/global/gkeMemberships/$MEMBERSHIP_NAME` and got error saying MISSING auth credentials. Which I believe is fine. However, above error in ArgoCD is still present. Any other idea?

Comment: Also, don't know if you saw, but I am able to impersonate service account and get cluster credentials and see running pods etc.

Comment: @golobitch OK. I have edited the answer to suggests additional elements to check.

Comment: can you please check Update #1 in the question. I am able to get token from the command in pod, but there is probably some underlying issue with fleet url / connection

Comment: @golobitch So an issue related to DNS resolution, then. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Even if a do a curl to connect gateway address, from the ArgoCD pod, I will get error saying that I am not authenticated / authorized, since I am calling this endpoint without token with curl. So this resolution looks ok. However, error still persist.

Comment: @golobitch OK. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Try and double-check the authentication setup in your ArgoCD configuration, making sure the correct tokens are being used and passed along in the requests to the Connect Gateway.
... this is already written in the question. there is a secret created per documentation to show how to authenticate to GKE cluster ...

Comment: @golobitch Good point. I have removed that last sentence from the answer.

Comment: Even though DNS resolution seems fine, the authentication or authorization is not passing through as expected when using the Connect Gateway URL in your ArgoCD configuration. => Exactly this ... and as stated in the question, this is the problem from begining, and my question is basically why is it not passing, how to check what is passing and how to force it to pass it? Any idea?

Comment: No, beside engaging with the ArgoCD or GKE support channels. To help diagnose the issue, you might consider deploying a network debugging tool within your Kubernetes cluster, such as a network capture tool or a logging agent that can provide detailed logs of the network requests being made by ArgoCD. (example: "[Debugging Kubernetes Network Traffic](https://indrabasak.github.io/debugging-k8s-network/)")

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your cluster connectgateway is global? I found that my regional cluster had the server pattern...

https://REGION-connectgateway.google.apis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/REGION/gkeMemberships/CLUSTER_MEMBERSHIP_NAME

I found this in $>kubectl config view

When I updated the server connection string it worked from ArgoCD.

Thanks for the initial post golobitch and the troubleshooting tips VonC

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to ... because." If you do not intend to provide an answer and are instead only saying "Thanks" please delete this. As an unregistered user you need to first register for that, or flag your own post for having a moderator do the deleting. Try for [answer] and please take the [tour].

Comment: Need to reorder for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Since publishing the "[Connect Gateway and ArgoCD: Deploy to Distributed Kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/connect-gateway-with-argocd)" blog post, Google has updated the API:

### Before (`/gkeMemberships`)

```
https://connectgateway.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/global/gkeMemberships/$MEMBERSHIP_NAME
```

### After (`/memberships/`)

```
https://connectgateway.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/global/memberships/$MEMBERSHIP_NAME
```

Comment: Not really. gkeMembership identifies a GKE cluster and is still valid. Best is to generate a kubeconfig https://cloud.google.com/anthos/multicluster-management/gateway/using#get_the_clusters_gateway_kubeconfig and use the connectgateway url reported there